# Apache Rewrite mode. Rewrite Rule

Tags: mod-rewrite

Links

```
http://example.com/en/media/.../img.jpg
http://example.com/en/media/.../style.css
http://example.com/en/media/.../script.js
http://example.com/en/media/.../file.pdf
http://example.com/en/media/.../file.doc
```

and other extensions...

I need to check extensions **(jpg|png|css|js|doc)** at the end of query string and remove language **(Part beetween http://example.com/ and /media/)**. I dont know how much and which specific symbols it will have.

en (En, English, En-en, En.en)
ru (Ru, Russian, Ru-ru, Ru.ru)

```
http://example.com/media/.../img.jpg
http://example.com/media/.../style.css
http://example.com/media/.../script.js
http://example.com/media/.../file.pdf
http://example.com/media/.../file.doc
```

Comment: _“I dont know how much and which specific symbols it will have”_ - but you know that it will always come first in the URL path, and before `/media/` ...

Comment: It's my rewrite condition: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/media/(.*)/(.*)\.(js|css). How can i remove lang prefix?

Comment: If your assets are not language-dependent, then how did the language get info those paths in the first place? Sounds like this might be a problem that you should rather fix where you _output_ those URLs, and not through rewriting. (Users switching to a different language would otherwise have to download all those assets again - the content might be the same, but the browser sees a different URL, so it can’t cache them.)

Comment: We have large project that use only one language. Now we want to add languages. We use lang module that define language. We write routes. But all of our includes of scripts and styles have url depend of system language and they doesn't exist.

Comment: _“But all of our includes of scripts and styles have url depend of system language and they doesn't exist”_ - well then fix _that_ ...? You should really fix the actual issue (your system is referring to static, non-language dependent assets _the wrong way_), and not try to cover it up via rewriting.

Comment: You want that i use mime types and file get contents to send file to browser?

Comment: No, I want you to set your system up properly, so that it creates URLs for those assets without the language specifier in them to begin with. _Why_ does it say `<img src="/en/media/.../img.jpg">` (I’m assuming?) in your HTML, and not `<img src="/media/.../img.jpg">` to begin with?

Comment: Links generated automatically. Yes in project links have difference views: 1) <img src="/en/media/.../img.jpg"> 2) <img src="/media/.../img.jpg">. I want to replace first view to second view.

Comment: Not a job for mod_rewrite at all then.